# Update, Insert, or Delete a Set into table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a *n* : *m* relationship between two tables, `Product` and `Tag`, called `ProductTag`. It has only two columns: `ProductId` and `TagId`.

The primary key is a composite of these two columns.

Inserting into this table is straight forward.

But, having a new set of tags that should be associated with the product, what are my options of updating the table in one go?

Right now, inside a transaction, I delete all product tags associated with a product, and insert the 'updated' ones. This works, is simple, and did not take a long time to code.

I'm still curious how it could be solved more elegantly, maybe even with PostgreSQL specific functionality?

**Example:**

Say you had 3 entries in this table:

```
product_id | tag_id
-----------+-------
1          | 2
1          | 3
1          | 6
```

A request arrives to update the product tags to look as follows:

```
product_id | tag_id
-----------+-------
1          | 3
1          | 6
1          | 7
```

Tag with `tag_id` 2 was removed, and a new tag with `tag_id` 7 was added. What is the best way of achieving this state in a single statement?

Comment: Please provide sample data to illustrate what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about the "usual" amount of tags - say "tens" of tags, rather than "thousands" - then the delete/insert approach isn't such a bad idea.

You can however do it in a single statement, that applies the changes:

```
with new_tags (product_id, tag_id) as (
  values (1,3),(1,6),(1,9)
), remove_tags as (
  delete from product_tag pt1
  using new_tags nt
  where pt1.product_id = nt.product_id
   and pt1.tag_id <> ALL (select tag_id from new_tags) 
)
insert into product_tag (product_id, tag_id)
select product_id, tag_id
from new_tags
on conflict do nothing;
```

The above assumes that `(product_id,tag_id)` is defined as the primary key in `product_tag`.

Online example: https://rextester.com/VVL1293